# Android LinearLayout always full width

Tags: android, xml, layout, android-linearlayout

I'm trying to design something like this for tablet devices

-640x480 area (left bound)-------flexible empty width--------control area(right bound)-

The flexible width is depending on the Tablet size bigger or smaller.
The Scrollpanes are for debugging on mobile devices only.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView11"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView12"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#24476D" >

            <view
                android:id="@+id/dmi"
                android:layout_width="640dp"
                android:layout_height="480dp"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                class="com.example.ecorailnet.DMIView"
                android:background="#8fc7ff" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/empty_list_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="List view is empty"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <view
                android:id="@+id/cpp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                class="com.example.ecorailnet.ControlPanel" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</ScrollView>
```

And finally the situation now and what it should look like.

[NOW](http://www7.pic-upload.de/14.08.12/tyswp1zydud7.png)

[AFTER](http://www7.pic-upload.de/14.08.12/93c3pkpbtbyn.png)

Thanks in advance

Greetings

Comment: I think you should use Relative layout and most outer layout should not be ScrollView...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want something on the left and something other on the right of the display, use a `RelativeLayout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#24476D" >

    <view
        android:id="@+id/dmi"
        android:layout_width="640dp"
        android:layout_height="480dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        class="com.example.ecorailnet.DMIView"
        android:background="#8fc7ff" />

    <view
        android:id="@+id/cpp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        class="com.example.ecorailnet.ControlPanel" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The only problem you can get is that the whole thing doesn't fit on a small screen. In that case the two views will overlap.

Comment: hi. thanks. 
1) how should i integrate scrollviews in your example in both directions?
2) andriod:layout_centerVertical="true" in the second view doesn't work
3) now it looks like this: [click](http://www7.pic-upload.de/16.08.12/2c4v3d5d95aq.png) Code is here: [click](http://pastebin.com/qFvELn9e)

Comment: Your top level containers are set to `wrap_content`. They should be set to `match_parent`. If you want to ensure that they have at least a certain size use the `minWidth` and `minHeight` attribute.

Comment: Which leads me to this error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'layout_width' with value 'match_parent') [code](http://pastebin.com/48ccPNBD)

Comment: Try `fill_parent` instead. `match_parent` got introduced in API 8.

Comment: ok..tried it and the view looks still like the screenshot on my first comment :( here's my latest [xml](http://pastebin.com/bs0eDZWM)

Comment: You didn't use the layout I postet at all. In Addition: What do you need the `ScrollViews` for?

Comment: sorry...wrong paste ;-) ... [here](http://pastebin.com/4yNx9QRc) is the right one..i need the scrollviews just for live debugging on smaller displays...i don't have a tablet yet for live debugging

Comment: Mh, I thought that should do it. I'll do some test later.

Comment: I tested the layout above on a tablet and it worked (apart from the andriod spelling mistaked which is now fixed). If it isn't working with the ScrollViews then it's the ScrollViews fault.

Answer (score 0):

If you are REALLY sure that you want a 640x480px DMIView.

You can try overriding the onMeasureMethod of DMIView

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    this.setMeasuredDimension(640,480);
}
```

Or If you want a right scaled DMIView that occupy all the height

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    int parentHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
    this.setMeasuredDimension(Math.round(parentHeight * 640 / 480f),parentHeight);      
}
```

Hope these would help.